# Selenium - why override 'apply' in custom Expected Conditions?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, apply

I can't find the answer and I'd like to understand why we do it this way, so: why, when creating custom ExpectedConditions, we have to override the **apply** method? It's most probably something simple and basic, but I just can't get it.

here's an example that I found online:

```
public boolean customExpectedConditions() {

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);

    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> jqLoaded = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
      @Override
      public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) { // why this part?
        try {
          return ((Long)((JavascriptExecutor)getDriver()).executeScript("return jQuery.active") == 0);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
          // no jQuery present
          return true;
        }
      }
    };

  return wait.until(jqLoaded);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override that because `Wait` implementations in Selenium (like `FluentWait`) expects implementation of `Function` interface to test the condition.

`ExpectedCondition<Boolean>` just extends that interface to restrict what goes to your "function" as a parameter. It restricts it to `WebDriver` objects.

So when you prepare your own condition you need to implement logic that would tell to Selenium that the condition is either met or not. You do that by overriding `apply` method.

You can find some more details of how waiters in Selenium work with conditions in the [case of `FluentWait`](https://www.webelement.click/en/selenium_webdriver_java_how_does_fluentwait_work_in_details) (other waiters work in the exactly same way).

You can also check this to find some [more examples of custom conditions](https://www.webelement.click/en/selenium_webdriver_java_custom_conditions_with_fluentwait) in Selenium and see that they are flexible enough to work for any sort of event you can detect with Java.